# Tab doesn't take full width in fragment

Tags: android, tabs

I am trying to create tabs using fragment layout. It is not set the **Full Width** of the screen and also tabs text is not displaying. Didn't find any solution to fix this. Below I added my code and screenshots of the output and what I want to achieve, please check any help will be appreciated.

Main Activity

```
public class SettingActivity extends Fragment {
    TabLayout tab;
    ViewPager vp;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_setting, container, false);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vp);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagering(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

ViewPager

```
public class ViewPagering extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int noTabs;
    private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"Tab1", "Tab2"};

    public ViewPagering(FragmentManager fm, int noTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.noTabs = noTabs;

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Frag1 f1 = new Frag1();

                return f1;
            case 1:
                frag2 f2 = new frag2();
                return f2;

            default:
                return null;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return noTabs;
    }
}
```

Xml

```
    LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="rarecrew.com.taberp.SettingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

[What I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1nlB.jpg)

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXYIn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO hi, I  want to add two tabs on my screen using fragment layout, it should take full width of the screen but it actually in my case is  width only as much text it has, i add two images, my output and what i want, please check, i hope i am able to clarify my question